# Adding a Y Axis to a google stacked column chart

Tags: html, google-visualization, yaxis

I have been creating column charts using the google chart tool, but am struggling to add a Y axis to my charts. I just need a standard series of values to appear on the axis on the left hand side of the chart.

I am able to create and manipulate the X axis but the Y axis will not appear for some reason. I'm sure there is something simple I am missing here.

Also apologies if the following code is messy, I am pretty new to this.

```
<head>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
  </script>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});     
  </script>
    <script language = "JavaScript">
                     function drawChart() {
                            // Define the chart to be drawn.
                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                ['Year','Orange','Orange2','Blue','Blue2','Green','Green2','Purple','Purple2','Brown','Brown2','Grey', 'Grey2', {role: 'annotation'}],
['2007',0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,''],
['2008',0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,''],
['2009',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,''],
['2010',0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,''],
['2011',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,''],
['2012',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,5,0,''],
['2013',0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,''],
['2014',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,''],
['2015',0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,''],
['2016',0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,''],
['2017',1,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,'']
                            ]);


        var colors = [
            { color: 'ff884d' },
            { color: 'ffddcc' },   
            { color: '3366ff' },
            { color: '99b3ff' },   
            { color: '33ff77' },
            { color: 'b3ffcc' },
            { color: 'd633ff' },   
            { color: 'f0b3ff' },
            { color: 'e6ccb3' },   
            { color: 'ac7339' },
            { color: 'c0c0c0' },
            { color: 'e6e6e6' },
        ];

                        var options = {
            isStacked:true,
            series: colors,
            bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
            legend: {position:'top', textStyle: {fontSize: 9}},
            chartArea: {  width: "100%"},
    axes: {
      y: {
        0: { side: 'left', label: 'Count'} 
    }}

            };  

                        // Instantiate and draw the chart.
                        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('publicbarchart'));
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                 }
                 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="publicbarchart" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the y-axis is being hidden by chart option --> `chartArea: {width: "100%"}`

`chartArea` controls the size of the center section where the bars are,
and does not include the labels on either axis or at the top

use `height` & `width` outside of `chartArea` for the entire chart

if you want to maximize the chart area, then set limits on `left`, `bottom`, `top`, and / or `right`,
recommend replacing with the following...

```
height: '100%',
width: '100%',
chartArea: {
  top: 32,
  left: 32,
  bottom: 32,
  right: 12,
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%'
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year','Orange','Orange2','Blue','Blue2','Green','Green2','Purple','Purple2','Brown','Brown2','Grey', 'Grey2', {role: 'annotation'}],
    ['2007',0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,''],
    ['2008',0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,''],
    ['2009',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,''],
    ['2010',0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,''],
    ['2011',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,''],
    ['2012',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,5,0,''],
    ['2013',0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,''],
    ['2014',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,''],
    ['2015',0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,''],
    ['2016',0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,''],
    ['2017',1,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,'']
  ]);

  var colors = [
    { color: 'ff884d' },
    { color: 'ffddcc' },
    { color: '3366ff' },
    { color: '99b3ff' },
    { color: '33ff77' },
    { color: 'b3ffcc' },
    { color: 'd633ff' },
    { color: 'f0b3ff' },
    { color: 'e6ccb3' },
    { color: 'ac7339' },
    { color: 'c0c0c0' },
    { color: 'e6e6e6' },
  ];

  var options = {
    isStacked:true,
    series: colors,
    bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
    legend: {position:'top', textStyle: {fontSize: 9}},
    axes: {
      y: {
        0: { side: 'left', label: 'Count'}
      }
    },
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    chartArea: {
      top: 32,
      left: 32,
      bottom: 32,
      right: 12,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```